# Hyperledger composer: Error: Could not find any functions to execute for transaction

Tags: javascript, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Before marking it duplicate because of this post

> [Why does transaction give this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47133754/why-does-transaction-give-this-error)
>   I want to mention this post have`nt solved  my problem.

my issue is that I am defining transaction in model file and then using it in js script but it throws an error  " Error: Could not find any functions to execute for transaction." when i try to execute it.

my cto code`
              /**
             * New model file
             */

```
       namespace org.acme.model

      participant Trader identified by email {
       o String email 
       o Double balance 
     }

          transaction simpleDemo {
        }`
```

---

js file

```
/**
      * @param {org.acme.model.simpleDemo} SimpleDemo
       * @transaction 
       */

     function SimpleDemo (SimpleDemo) 
     {
  console.log('hello');
      }
```

picture is attached for reference. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zys9T.png)

Answer (score 4):

In above stated case if there is a space between 
where our param is ending and where we define our function, hyperledger composer will throw the error.

You have to write it like this without any space.

```
/**
 * @param {org.acme.model.simpleDemo} SimpleDemo
 * @transaction 
 */
function SimpleDemo (SimpleDemo) 
{
    console.log('hello');
}
```

Thank you @lakshay gaur for solving this issue.